# Algorithm for sorting loosely comparable data?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, language-agnostic

Let's say I have an unsorted list of four objects: `[B, C, A, D]`.

All four objects are of the same type, and:

```
  (A > B),
  (C > D),
  (A != C or D)
  (B != C or D)
  (C != A or B)
  (D != A or B).
```

By `!=` I mean that they are neither less-than, equal-to, or greater-than the other objects.

I need to "sort" the list such that `A` will always come before `B`, and `C` will always come before `D`. Beyond those two requirements, I have no demand on the ordering of the list; therefore, given the previously described list, the sort function should return either `[A, B, C, D]` or `[C, D, A, B]`.

As for the cause of this problem, I am trying to sort an array of `java.lang.Class` objects based on their relationships to each other. For example, if `A` is the super-class/super-interface of `B`, then `A` is less-than `B`. If `A` extends/implements `B`, then is `A` greater-than `B`. If `A` is `B`, then obviously `A` equals `B`. Otherwise, `A` is completely non-comparable toB.

Comment: This is called "topological sort".  You need to establish the "greater than" relationships, and from there you can compute a "rank" value for every element with a simple recursive function: the rank of an element is the rank of what it's greater than + 1, or else 1. Then you can sort normally on the rank.

Comment: I think you need to explain why [A, C, B, D], [A, C, D, B], [C, A, D, B] and [C, A, B, D] aren't a valid solution. Or do you just want to keep comparable objects together. Then you should make something that will determine "an" order of that: Comparability of these should become before comparability of those.

Comment: What's the question? Why can't you always output [A, B, C, D] if you know this to be correct?

Comment: @ontrack Those alternate solutions would also work. I am simply trying to ensure that if [X] > [Y], then [X] will come before [Y], after sorting.

Comment: @IVlad The given list is only an example. In reality, the input could have hundreds of elements; therefore, there is no single correct output from the sort function.

Comment: @Pointy - why are you introducing a rank? Isn't this a classic topological sort where `x > y` relationships are directed edges?

Comment: Yes, but that's a way of doing the sort. You follow the edges recursively (of course it better be a DAG) and that lets you concoct easily sortable values. Once you've got those you apply a traditional simple sort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Build a graph. For each two elements `x` and `y` such that `x > y`, add a directed edge from `x` to `y`. In your example you'd have `A -> B` and `C -> D`. Then run [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) on this graph. The topological sort returned will be a possible solution.